# Arrange data set using python

Tags: python, excel, dataset

I am trying to rearrange my data set using python which currently looks like this (sample of the data)

[image]

to this:

[image]

like a matrix. I want to how many students take one course or both courses. by referring to the id number for each student. Would anybody be so kind to help me get started in the right direction?

Comment: How are you re-arranging it?

Comment: I have a very large data set (this sample of it), I wanna using python to make it like the second image shown if that is possible.

Comment: I got that, but how are you getting the second table from the first? where does the 1 and 71 come from for example

Comment: ok, I just edit the image to match the given sample. it is like a matrix. want to how many students take one course or both courses. by referring to the id number for each student

Comment: You should put that explanation into your question

Comment: editing done...

Comment: I find a similar answer to my Q.
you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370709/create-a-matrix-from-two-columns